# Laravel E-mail verification (re-send method)

Tags: php, laravel, api, email, verification

**TLDR**: I am new to Laravel but I am trying to re-send a verify e-mail to an e-mail adress through a request->input('email').

**Case:**

*[Working]*
When a user registrates I send out an e-mail to the registrated user through Laravels default e-mail verification scaffolding. Before the user can use the platform it needs to be verified. The user get's an e-mail and can click on the button in the e-mail to verify it's account.

*[Not working]*
But if a user for some reason lost his/her verification e-mail I want to re-send it through an API call while checking (but not exposing) if the e-mail filled in, is available. This is not supported by default in Laravels e-mail verification scaffolding.

**What have I done:**

- Added in the user model: `implements MustVerifyEmail` which uses `use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;`
- In the default VerificationController I changed: `$this->middleware('auth')` to `$this->middleware('auth')->except(['resend']);`
- In api.php added two routes to a custom VerifyEmailController class

  - `Route::group(['middleware' => ['signed', 'throttle:6,1']], function () { Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', [VerifyEmailController::class, '__invoke'])->name('verification.verify'); });` **[This works]**
  - `Route::group(['middleware' => ['throttle:6,1']], function () { Route::post('/email/verify/resend', [VerifyEmailController::class, 'resend'])->name('verification.resend');});`
    **[Call works but resend method logic is wrong]**
- And this is my VerifyEmailController class resend method
  [image: VerifyEmailController resend method]

Ofcourse this is not how it's done, but I can't think of a way to make this work due to my lack of knowledge and experience.

Right now I do get a json response back that it has send the e-mail, but obviously it has not fired the Verify event to actually send the verification e-mail in the request.

[image: Json response that e-mail has been send to e-mail request]

If you want more screenshots of code let me know.

***Solution from*** [Wael Khalifa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71221768/4866241) :

in api.php I declared the following route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['throttle:6,1']], function () {
Route::post('/email/verify/resend', [VerifyEmailController::class, 'resend'])->name('verification.resend');});
```

in the VerifyEmailController class, declared the following method

```
class VerifyEmailController extends Controller
{

    public function resend(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:45',
        ]);
        
        // These two lines below where the solution to my problem.
        $user = User::where('email', $request->input('email'))->first();
        $user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

        return Response::json(["status" => 'Verification e-mail send.', "email" => $request->input('email')], 201);
    }
}
```

Comment: **Never** share screenshots of your code. That is text, and it should be shared as text. Also, please share your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: The answer below by Wael Khalifa was exactly the solution I was going for. For the future I will indeed share in code, instead of images. I will update my question with the answer implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get user from your database after that use sendEmailVerificationNotification() method to resend the verification email

```
 Route::post('resend/verification-email', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
$user = User::where('email',$request->input('email'))->first();

    $user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

    return 'your response';
})->middleware('throttle:6,1');
```

You can do the same thing in your controller if you need help with that add a comment to me

Hope the answer help you

Comment: That was exactly it. I was staring myself completely blind! Thank you!

Comment: Your always welcome 